# Updating the Matlab GUI with Popup menus with callback functions

Tags: matlab

I am using a Matlab GUI for updating Popup menus from the database server. I am able to update the data in the workspace, but after I set the values in the callback it shows the error:

> Warning: 'popupmenu' control requires that 'Value' be an integer within String range. Control will not be rendered until all of its parameter values are valid

I am able to set the popup the first time but when I select the next one it shows the error.

```
{

function Load_Location_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
global DatabaseConnection
%DatabaseConnection = connect2SEdB('Open');
global LoadFilter
% LoadFilter = {  'Category' 'Type'  'SubType'   'Make'  'Model' 'LoadLocation'  'SerialNumber'; ... 
%                 'ANY'      'ANY'   'ANY'       'ANY'   'ANY'   'ANY'           'ANY'; ...
%                 NaN        NaN     NaN         NaN     NaN     NaN             NaN };
%CurrentLoadSelection = queryLoadFilter( DatabaseConnection , LoadFilter);
global CurrentLoadSelection
dataLoadLocation = CurrentLoadSelection{2,6};% Imports the Load Location
val = get(handles.Load_Location,'Value');%Gets the value of specific column
global Load_Location_list 
Load_Location_list = get(handles.Load_Location,'String');% Gets the Name of that Value
Selected_string1 = Load_Location_list{val};%Stores in Selected String
SelectedItem1 = val;%
% disp(Selected_string);
% disp(SelectedItem);
assignin('base','Load_Location_list',Load_Location_list{val});%Makes it in Workspace
x= strcmp(Load_Location_list{val}, dataLoadLocation(:,2));%Finds the Specific Selected Data
%disp(x)%Displays it in Command Center for CODER 
New_Value_Load=(flip(transpose(dataLoadLocation(x,:))));
disp(New_Value_Load);
disp(LoadFilter(2:3,6))
LoadFilter(2:3,6)=New_Value_Load;
disp(LoadFilter)
% disp(dataLoadType(x,:))
assignin('base','LoadFilter',LoadFilter);
CurrentLoadSelection = queryLoadFilter(DatabaseConnection, LoadFilter);
assignin('base','CurrentLoadSelection',CurrentLoadSelection);
disp(CurrentLoadSelection)
guidata(hObject,handles);
%%Database Query to Load Location
% dataLoadLocation = CurrentLoadSelection{2,6};
% % disp(dataLoadLocation)
% % x=find(strcmp(Category_list{val}, dataLoadLocation(:,2)));
% % disp(x)
% % disp(dataLoadLocation(x,:))
% set(handles.Load_Location,'String',dataLoadLocation(:,2));
%%Database Query to Load Model
dataLoadModel = CurrentLoadSelection{2,5};
set(handles.Model,'String',dataLoadModel(:,2));
%%Database Query to Load Serial Number
dataLoadSerialNumber = CurrentLoadSelection{2,7};
set(handles.LocalSerialNumber,'String',dataLoadSerialNumber(:,2));
%%Database Query to Load Sub Type
dataLoadSubtype = CurrentLoadSelection{2,3};
set(handles.Sub_Type,'String',dataLoadSubtype(:,2));
%%Database Query to Load Category
dataLoadCategory = CurrentLoadSelection{2,1};
set(handles.Load_Category,'String',dataLoadCategory(:,2));
%Database Query to Load Type
dataLoadType = CurrentLoadSelection{2,2};
set(handles.Type,'String',dataLoadType(:,2));
%Database Query to Load Make
dataLoadMake = CurrentLoadSelection{2,4};
set(handles.Make,'String',dataLoadMake(:,2));
guidata(hObject,handles);
```

}

I am using Database Connection to call a query which updates the **CurrentLoadSelection** and which in turn updates the remaining popup menus. But once I try to select the other popupmenu selection, it shows the above mentioned Error.

Comment: Post your code, so that we can try to help you. by the way the warning message indicates you have an issue with the popup value, check what happen where you modify it.

Comment: @alexmogavero I am using Guide for this program. So I have to work with  handles to update the result.

Comment: In this code what is the popup that does not render?

Comment: @alexmogavero The CurrentLoadSelection is responsible to update the respective popups everytime when you select an entry in any one of the popup-menus. So basically its(CurrentLoadSelection ) in base workspace which automatically updates in workspace. It because of the queries I have written for them for Database. But Its having problems to reflect back in popups.

Comment: please explain better your problem. What exactly does not work? The message is a warning not an error. In the cose which is the popup object that does not work? `LocalSerialNumber`, `Sub_Type` or what?

Comment: I see. i posted a possible solution.

Comment: What type of data is contained in `dataLoadSubtype(:,2)`?

Comment: @excaza it is cell array(n,2), where n can change as per the query return values from the Database.

Comment: I would use [the debugger](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/debugging-process-and-features.html) or display the value of `dataLoadSubtype(:,2)` to examine the return as you're assigning it. If it's not always going to assign valid data to the `String` property of your `popupmenu` then you need to incorporate logic to handle it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible that the issue happen when you reset the String property of the popup `Sub_Type`.
The property Value shall satisfly the following: `Value<=length(String)`.
To avoid problems after resetting String do:

```
set(handles.Sub_Type,'String',dataLoadSubtype(:,2));
str = get(handles.Sub_Type,'String');
if isempty(str)
    error('Oops this should not happen!');
else
    set(handles.Sub_Type,'Value',1);
end
```

Be sure to check that you do not put an empty array in String

Comment: I tried to use the one you said but it shows the error on other Popup now. Is it because each case it is not able to match the Value??. Do we have some provision for having the default command to set the value to universal.

Comment: @Piyush I think you have to do this on every popup whenever you change the String property, because the Value is not reset automatically when you set the String. To avoid writing the same code every time just create a function to change the String